# How to show hexdecimal view of integers in Clion and PyCharm?

Tags: debugging, hex, clion, jetbrains-ide

I found this help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/using-hexadecimal-view.html

but it relies on long keystroke to call maintenance popup, which is probably not working on my machine (a lot of keystrokes not working).

Is it possible to call this setting w/o keystroke?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following trick. In the Variables view add ".hex()" for bytearray

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can call Help | Find Action (or press double Shift) and search for 'Maintenance'.